# Why is my android RadioButton text being truncated at the beginning?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a really weird layout problem... basically the first button in this RadioGroup is losing it's first letter, as per this screenshot (it should say "Booked Off", not "ooked Off"):

[image: mangled RadioButton text screenshot]

The XML fragment is fairly simple (and I've got nothing funny in an external style or anything):

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RadioGroup android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+shift_edit/bookoff"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Booked Off" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+shift_edit/ado"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="ADO" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+shift_edit/working"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Working" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone recognise the problem here and can offer a solution?  I'm using 1.6 if it matters, because the device I'm targetting only has a 1.6 ROM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after deploying my app to a real (Android 1.6) device, it appears that the problem is in the emulator.  I can't reproduce it on a real device.  Also, as user432209 mentioned, it doesn't appear to show up in later emulators.  Even better, it only shows up the *first* time you render an activity; go out and back in, and it's back to normal.  So I guess all in all it's a pretty minor defect that can be ignored.

Comment: For anyone wondering - this is exactly right. Had this exact problem, and thank you to womble for posting your question so closely in line with my query in google.

Comment: I honestly can't rate this up enough... I spent two hours trying to figure out what the hell was going on testing different emulators, devices, etc. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just dumped your code into an emulator and came up empty handed.  It works fine on 2.1, 2.2, and 2.3 in all 11 generic emulator styles.

I would start with the easy/generic solutions.  Reboot, make a new emulator, make a new layout, etc etc.

Comment: That reminds me... I'm using 1.6 (because I'm targetting a device which only has that old a ROM).  Question updated.